# How to find users per 15 minutes from given time range

Tags: sql-server, business-intelligence

I tried to write a SQL query to show the count of users for every 15 mins of the time range.

**Source Table**

```
  User  |      Start Date       |       End Date        
 -------|-----------------------|----------------------- 
  User1 | 28/06/2018 3:53:00 PM | 28/06/2018 4:30:00 PM 
  User2 | 28/06/2018 3:45:00 PM | 28/06/2018 4:15:00 PM
```

**Desired output**

```
          Date          | Count 
 -----------------------|------- 
  28/06/2018 3:45:00 PM |     1 
  28/06/2018 4:00:00 PM |     2 
  28/06/2018 4:15:00 PM |     2 
  28/06/2018 4:30:00 PM |     1
```

Comment: what is the logic here ? please explain

Comment: Now I have two people with their attendance, my purpose is to check how many people there every 15 minutes.